Non-existent landmarks when using mediapipe
I'm currently using Mediapipe holistic remote to draw landmarks on frames produced by a webcam stream. I want to use the coordinates of the shoulder, elbow, wrist and index finger to calculate the angle between the different parts of the arm. That is working, however my code is also producing angles when the required landmarks are not to be seen in the webcam footage.
I simplified the problem and have found that mediapipe holistic is determining all 33 landmarks regardless of how many can actually be recognised. I added a line of code to my code so that all landmarks get saved to a seperate text file. When I held only my index finger in front of the webcam, 33 landmarks appeared in the text file.

It is a documented and intended behaviour of MediaPipe - it always generates all the landmarks, even when they cannot be observed. To determine which landmarks are actually present (observable) in the image, you should use the visibility value associated with each landmark.
Here is an example of how these values are checked in the draw_landmarks() function of MediaPipe's mp.solutions.drawing_utils:
  for idx, landmark in enumerate(landmark_list.landmark):
    if ((landmark.HasField('visibility') and
         landmark.visibility < _VISIBILITY_THRESHOLD))

where landmark_list is actually results.pose_landmarks obtained from holistic.process().
Landmark class is described in official doumentation and github docs.
